# JQuery UI datepicker in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have tried to use some of the widgets in `JQuery UI` on an `Asp.Net MVC` site without luck.

For example the basic datepicker from [jQuery UI - functional demos](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/tags/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker).

I have created a simple MVC project and added the script references in `Site.Master` like this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />"
```

In the `Index.aspx` file I have cleared all default content and added the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#basics").datepicker();     
</script>  
<input type="text" size="10" value="click here" id="basics"/>
```

The core jQuery works fine. Any clues?

Comment: See my tutorial which does this exactly. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

Comment: The link in your question is broken, does anyone know the correct link?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure your initializer is called after the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#basics").datepicker();
});
```

[jQuery ready event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn):

> By using this method, your bound
>   function will be called the instant
>   the DOM is ready to be read and
>   manipulated, which is when 99.99% of
>   all JavaScript code needs to run.

Answer (score 7):

I've got a write-up of this with MVC 3 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Comment: Stuarts great blog motivated my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are executing the JavaScript inline as the page loads. In which case the `#basics` selector won't be able to locate the input with `id="basics"` as it hasn't yet been parsed and rendered in to the document body.

Your solution may be as simple as as moving the `script` element in your code to a position after the `input` element.

Better still, subscribe to a document ready or document loaded event and execute the jQuery code in the handler of that event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#basics").datepicker();
});
```

There's a number of advantages to that. You can be sure that the entire DOM is ready for use, and there is no dependency on the order of the source code meaning you could move the JavaScript to an external file in the future to take advantage of various caching mechanisms on the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Where in the page are you loading scripts & where are you calling the datepicker initialization?

Here is a sample of using jQuery shorthand document ready & css selectors to initialize datePickers more easily.

Here is the razor code for a sample input box (notice the "datefield" css class)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control datefield" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript needed to initialize any datepicker by css selector

```
﻿$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker();
});
```

I've put together a tutorial detailing the specifics & a sample ASP.NET MVC5 solution on github

http://prestoasp.net/using-the-jquery-datepicker-with-asp-net-mvc/
https://github.com/fredo007/i6technology/tree/master/InsuranceSales