# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't work in IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I've have finally got the datepicker to work on my MVC demo site. One thing though it doesn't work when browsing with IE7, I havn't testet with IE6 yet. Does anyone know how to fix this problem or can't I use jQuery if I want IE users to be able to pick dates?

It works like a charm on Safari and Firefox, except for it's position when dropping down.

Please try for yourself on my demo site: [Demo site](http://www.tarsius.se)

Click the link "Boka plats" on the menu. then login with: 
email: test@test.nu
password: tester

Comment: can you update your question to include your JQuery code so far?

Comment: broken in IE6 too, Expected Identifier, String or number, Line 96, Char 17. I think eagle eye steve_c has found the problem comma

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you have a trailing comma in your parameter list. IE will choke on trailing commas all the time in js.

Try this:

```
$(function() {            
    $("#Date").datepicker($.extend({},
       $.datepicker.regional["sv"], {
            onSelect: function(date) {
            }, 
            minDate: "0d",
            maxDate: new Date(2009, 3 - 1, 26),
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            highlightWeek: true, 
            showOn: "both",
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            firstDay: 1,
            buttonImage:"../../Content/Images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showAnim: "scale", 
            showOptions: { 
                origin: ["top", "left"] 
            }
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your eagle eyes, i fell a bit embaressed to have missed that.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to be of help. Js errors can sometimes be so simple, but infuriating.

Comment: I know this is old but had to say it, everybody misses THAT DAMN ,! THREE F*** HOURS FOR A DAMN ,

Answer (score 0):

[Is this helpful at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385269/jquery-ui-datepicker-in-aspnet-mvc)

EDIT: Yes, I think you need to wrap your DatePicker() in $(document).ready(function()
EX:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            $("#Date").datepicker($.extend({},
                $.datepicker.regional["sv"], {
                    onSelect: function(date) {
                        //alert("The chosen date is " + date);
                    }, 
                    minDate: "0d",
                    maxDate: new Date(2009, 3 - 1, 26),
                    showStatus: true,
                    showWeeks: true,
                    highlightWeek: true, 
                    showOn: "both",
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    buttonImage:"../../Content/Images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showAnim: "scale", 
                    showOptions: { 
                        origin: ["top", "left"] 
                    }, 
                }));
        });   
    </script>
```

Comment: Just looking at his example with Firebug, I can see that he does attach the datepicker to the input in document.ready (he uses the shorthand $(function(){});   )

Comment: Sorry about that. I viewed the source code from IE and I could've sworn I didn't see it then. Sorry about that and good luck.