# JQuery DataPicker not working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using the JQuery `DatePicker` for selecting date in text boxes. The code i am using is given below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showAnim: "fold",
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            constrainInput: true,
            firstDay: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and IE versions 9 and above. But its not working in IE versions 7 and 8. Then i also tried the following like but still the same, it works in IE 9 and above but not in IE 7 and 8.

[JQuery UI DataPicker doesnt work in IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390105/jquery-ui-datepicker-doesnt-work-in-ie7)

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong and how to do this? I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the JQuery script i am referring is as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that the 2.x branch of  jQuery removed support for IE6 and 7. You may want to try 1.12 - assuming the datepicker plugin itself even supports versions of IE that are that old.

Comment: That stinks that you have to support IE7....

Comment: I will look into that and try..thank you

Comment: @MisterPositive yes its for a client and they only use IE7 so they recommend me to make compatible for that

Comment: Use the 1.8.3 version, although we don't support it -- our dp functionality works with IE 7.

Comment: i tried 1.4.1 and 1.11.1 both are not working..ok i will try 1.8.3

Comment: 1.8.3 also not working..should i change something in the JQuery i mentioned in the question? Im using the `jquery-1.8.3.min.js`and `jquery-1.8.3.js` files any other files needed?

Answer (score 3):

The 2.x branch of jQuery does not support IE 8  and below, from the [documentation](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/05/01/jquery-1-11-1-and-2-1-1-released/)

> The 1.x branch includes support for IE 6/7/8 and the 2.x branch does not.

You'll have to swap to the 1.x branch

Also note that [current versions](https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/) of jQuery UI only supports IE 11 officially

Comment: Oh i see..ok i will check that..Thank you..any version of 1.x is fine?

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC - yes, it should be, but when dealing with old IE versions you should always check the support for each library you intend to use, as most have abandoned anything older than IE 9